# Python writing a long int as a binary value to a file

Tags: python, file-io, type-conversion, primes, binary-data

I have been trying to take a long int (m39 prime) and store it as a binary file.
When I attempt to write the bin value to a file it is written as a string.

```
>>> m39 = bin(2**13466917-1)
>>> open('m39', 'wb').write(m39) 
madsc13ntist@jaberwock:~/Desktop$ xxd m39 | head
0000000: 3062 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131  0b11111111111111
0000010: 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131  1111111111111111
0000020: 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131  1111111111111111
0000030: 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131  1111111111111111
0000040: 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131  1111111111111111
0000050: 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131  1111111111111111
0000060: 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131  1111111111111111
0000070: 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131  1111111111111111
0000080: 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131  1111111111111111
```

I'm feeling pretty certain that there is a ridiculously simple answer to this but I haven't been successful at converting m39 into a bytearray or a buffer for writing.  Should I be using io or memoryview, etc.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance anyone can provide. :)

I am using Python 2.7.3 and I prefer to us builtin modules if at all possible.

EDIT: I am attempting to store the value as a binary file which would occupy much less space on the disk/memory.  I understand that the bin type is a string in python but I am attempting to write `\x11\x11\x11\x11 not \x31\x31\x31\x31`.  My intent is not to print a string representation of the value, but to store it efficiently for later use/manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

You should either use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module or [array](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) depending on structure of the data (i.e. for an array of homogenous values, array will be simpler/faster).

Answer (score 2):

The Python `pickle` module is pretty efficient.  The representation is only 8 bytes longer than the raw binary value can be stored into.  This works in Python 2.X or 3.X:

```
import pickle
m39 = 2**13466917-1
with open('m39.dat','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(m39,f,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Resulting hex dump (1,683,373 bytes):

```
 80 03 8B A5 AF 19 00 FF FF FF ... FF FF FF 1F 2E
```

To read back:

```
import pickle
with open('m39.dat','rb') as f:
   m39 = pickle.load(f)
```

Python 3 also has `to_bytes` and `from_bytes` methods on integers, but requires a little more work as the length of the integer in bytes has to be computed.

```
import math
m39 = 2**13466917-1
s = m39.to_bytes(math.ceil(m39.bit_length()/8),'little')
with open('m39.dat','wb') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Resulting hex dump (1,683,365 bytes):

```
 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ... FF FF FF FF 1F
```

To read back:

```
with open('m39.dat','rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
m39 = int.from_bytes(data,'little')
```

Obviously there is a pattern there and it would be more efficient to just store the exponent of the prime instead.